# Join excel files based on an non-equal time variable

Tags: r, vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to join 2 excel files

the 1st one contine this column:

```
01/01/2016 00:00
01/01/2016 00:10
01/01/2016 00:20
01/01/2016 00:30
01/01/2016 00:40
01/01/2016 00:50
01/01/2016 01:00
01/01/2016 01:10
01/01/2016 01:20
01/01/2016 01:30
01/01/2016 01:40
01/01/2016 01:50
01/01/2016 02:00
01/01/2016 02:10
01/01/2016 02:20
01/01/2016 02:30
01/01/2016 02:40
01/01/2016 02:50
01/01/2016 03:00
01/01/2016 03:10
01/01/2016 03:20
01/01/2016 03:30
01/01/2016 03:40
01/01/2016 03:50
01/01/2016 04:00
01/01/2016 04:10
01/01/2016 04:20
01/01/2016 04:30
01/01/2016 04:40
01/01/2016 04:50
01/01/2016 05:00
01/01/2016 05:10
01/01/2016 05:20
01/01/2016 05:30
01/01/2016 05:40
01/01/2016 05:50
01/01/2016 06:00
01/01/2016 06:10
01/01/2016 06:20
01/01/2016 06:30
01/01/2016 06:40
01/01/2016 06:50
01/01/2016 07:00
01/01/2016 07:10
01/01/2016 07:20
01/01/2016 07:30
01/01/2016 07:40
01/01/2016 07:50
01/01/2016 08:00
01/01/2016 08:10
01/01/2016 08:20
01/01/2016 08:30
01/01/2016 08:40
01/01/2016 08:50
01/01/2016 09:00
01/01/2016 09:10
01/01/2016 09:20
01/01/2016 09:30
01/01/2016 09:40
01/01/2016 09:50
01/01/2016 10:00
01/01/2016 10:10
01/01/2016 10:20
01/01/2016 10:30
01/01/2016 10:40
01/01/2016 10:50
01/01/2016 11:00
01/01/2016 11:10
01/01/2016 11:20
01/01/2016 11:30
01/01/2016 11:40
01/01/2016 11:50
01/01/2016 12:00
01/01/2016 12:10
01/01/2016 12:20
01/01/2016 12:30
01/01/2016 12:40
01/01/2016 12:50
01/01/2016 13:00
01/01/2016 13:10
01/01/2016 13:20
01/01/2016 13:30
01/01/2016 13:40
01/01/2016 13:50
01/01/2016 14:00
01/01/2016 14:10
01/01/2016 14:20
01/01/2016 14:30
01/01/2016 14:40
01/01/2016 14:50
01/01/2016 15:00
01/01/2016 15:10
01/01/2016 15:20
01/01/2016 15:30
01/01/2016 15:40
01/01/2016 15:50
01/01/2016 16:00
01/01/2016 16:10
01/01/2016 16:20
01/01/2016 16:30
01/01/2016 16:40
01/01/2016 16:50
01/01/2016 17:00
01/01/2016 17:10
01/01/2016 17:20
01/01/2016 17:30
01/01/2016 17:40
01/01/2016 17:50
01/01/2016 18:00
01/01/2016 18:10
01/01/2016 18:20
01/01/2016 18:30
01/01/2016 18:40
01/01/2016 18:50
01/01/2016 19:00
01/01/2016 19:10
01/01/2016 19:20
01/01/2016 19:30
01/01/2016 19:40
01/01/2016 19:50
01/01/2016 20:00
01/01/2016 20:10
01/01/2016 20:20
01/01/2016 20:30
01/01/2016 20:40
01/01/2016 20:50
01/01/2016 21:00
01/01/2016 21:10
01/01/2016 21:20
01/01/2016 21:30
01/01/2016 21:40
01/01/2016 21:50
01/01/2016 22:00
01/01/2016 22:10
01/01/2016 22:20
01/01/2016 22:30
01/01/2016 22:40
01/01/2016 22:50
01/01/2016 23:00
01/01/2016 23:10
01/01/2016 23:20
01/01/2016 23:30
01/01/2016 23:40
01/01/2016 23:50
```

and for the second one :

```
01/01/2016 05:07
01/01/2016 07:10
01/01/2016 08:19
01/01/2016 08:27
01/01/2016 09:18
01/01/2016 10:13
01/01/2016 10:23
01/01/2016 10:30
01/01/2016 10:57
01/01/2016 12:20
01/01/2016 14:50
01/01/2016 14:54
01/01/2016 15:00
01/01/2016 15:20
01/01/2016 16:12
01/01/2016 18:26
01/01/2016 19:08
01/01/2016 20:00
01/01/2016 21:15
01/01/2016 21:20
01/01/2016 22:10
01/01/2016 22:13
01/01/2016 22:18
```

and i need to do the join btw them based on the nearest value from the 1st excel file to the 2nd.

I've tried vlookup and power query but they assume equality between column's values.

I really need your help.

Thank you so much.

Comment: `vLookup` doesn't need equality if your data is sorted and you set the 4th parameter to `True`

Comment: Please, define "nearest value"...

Comment: Seems like you can just join the two and sort it alfabetically?

Comment: nearest value means like if I have 01/01/2016 22:18 and i need to join that row with the appropriate one from the 1st excel file i would choose 01/01/2016 22:20

Comment: What about `01/01/2016 22:10` and `01/01/2016 22:13`? The nearest value is `01/01/2016 22:10` for both?

Comment: Yes Marciej Los.

Comment: data maths, do any of the answers work for you? If so, please accept one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your longer list is in column A and your shorter list is in column B (assuming no headers etc.), then the following formula would VLOOKUP the nearest lower value:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,A:A,1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

An R solution. All `merge` (and `dplyr::*_join`) operators work on equality, so your first problem is converting your first vector to the closest in the second. The `findInterval` function is similar to the `VLOOKUP` function in Excel:

```
findInterval(v1df$v1, v2df$v2)
#  [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
```

This shows two artifacts:

1. The first value has an index of `0`, indicating that it is before the first value in `v2` (your second vector).
2. This doesn't provide the *closest*, it is the highest without going over.

We can shift `v2` to accommodate.

```
d <- diff(v2df$v2)
units(d) <- "secs"
v2df$v2shift <- v2df$v2 - c(d[1], d)/2
v2df
#                    v2             v2shift
# 1 2016-01-01 05:07:00 2016-01-01 04:05:30
# 2 2016-01-01 07:10:00 2016-01-01 06:08:30
# 3 2016-01-01 08:19:00 2016-01-01 07:44:30
```

Now the interval works:

```
findInterval(v1df$v1, v2df$v2shift)
#  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
```

Now we add that to the first data:

```
v1df$closest <- v2df$v2[findInterval(v1df$v1, v2df$v2shift)]
v1df
#                     v1             closest
# 1  2016-01-01 05:00:00 2016-01-01 05:07:00
# 2  2016-01-01 05:10:00 2016-01-01 05:07:00
# 3  2016-01-01 05:20:00 2016-01-01 05:07:00
# 4  2016-01-01 06:40:00 2016-01-01 07:10:00
# 5  2016-01-01 06:50:00 2016-01-01 07:10:00
# 6  2016-01-01 07:00:00 2016-01-01 07:10:00
# 7  2016-01-01 07:10:00 2016-01-01 07:10:00
# 8  2016-01-01 07:20:00 2016-01-01 07:10:00
# 9  2016-01-01 08:00:00 2016-01-01 08:19:00
# 10 2016-01-01 08:10:00 2016-01-01 08:19:00
```

and merge:

```
merge(v2df["v2"], v1df, by.x="v2", by.y="closest")
#                     v2                  v1
# 1  2016-01-01 05:07:00 2016-01-01 05:00:00
# 2  2016-01-01 05:07:00 2016-01-01 05:10:00
# 3  2016-01-01 05:07:00 2016-01-01 05:20:00
# 4  2016-01-01 07:10:00 2016-01-01 06:40:00
# 5  2016-01-01 07:10:00 2016-01-01 06:50:00
# 6  2016-01-01 07:10:00 2016-01-01 07:00:00
# 7  2016-01-01 07:10:00 2016-01-01 07:10:00
# 8  2016-01-01 07:10:00 2016-01-01 07:20:00
# 9  2016-01-01 08:19:00 2016-01-01 08:00:00
# 10 2016-01-01 08:19:00 2016-01-01 08:10:00
```

Similarly

```
dplyr::full_join(v2df["v2"], v1df, by=c("v2"="closest"))
```

---

Data:

```
v1 <- as.POSIXct(c(
  '01/01/2016 05:00',
  '01/01/2016 05:10',
  '01/01/2016 05:20',
  '01/01/2016 06:40',
  '01/01/2016 06:50',
  '01/01/2016 07:00',
  '01/01/2016 07:10',
  '01/01/2016 07:20',
  '01/01/2016 08:00',
  '01/01/2016 08:10'), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

v2 <- as.POSIXct(c(
  '01/01/2016 05:07',
  '01/01/2016 07:10',
  '01/01/2016 08:19'), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

v1df <- data.frame(v1 = v1)
v2df <- data.frame(v2 = v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a string like `01/01/2016 08:00` is valid date in your system, you can use VBA solution within ADODB:

```
'needs reference to MS ActiveX Data Object Library x.x reference
'menu: Tools->References... in VBA Code Pane

Sub GetDataByNearestDates()
    Dim sSQL As String, sConn As String
    Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRst As ADODB.Recordset

    On Error GoTo Err_GetDataByNearestDates

    sSQL = "SELECT t1.A, t2.B, t1.A - t2.B" & vbCr
    sSQL = sSQL & "FROM (" & vbCr
    sSQL = sSQL & "SELECT [F1] AS A FROM [Sheet1$]" & vbCr
    sSQL = sSQL & ") AS t1" & vbCr
    sSQL = sSQL & ", (" & vbCr
    sSQL = sSQL & "SELECT [F1] AS B FROM [Sheet2$]" & vbCr
    sSQL = sSQL & ") AS t2" & vbCr
    sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE ((t1.A-t2.B >-0.004) AND (t1.A-t2.B <=0.004));" & vbCr

    'if you use column-headers, change HDR=NO to HDR=YES
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=NO';"

    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    With oConn
        .ConnectionString = sConn
        .Open
        Set oRst = oConn.Execute(sSQL)
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells.Clear
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset oRst

Exit_GetDataByNearestDates:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not oRst Is Nothing Then oRst.Close: Set oRst = Nothing
    If Not oConn Is Nothing Then oConn.Close: Set oConn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_GetDataByNearestDates:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_GetDataByNearestDates

End Sub
```

Above code produces a result set of 'nearest values' in Sheet3

To be able to use above code, you'll need:

1. create an empty Excel file (with 3 worksheets)
2. copy data from workbook1 into `Sheet1`
3. copy data from workbook2 into `Sheet2`
4. go to VBA Code Pane (`ALT`+`F11`)
5. insert new module (menu `Insert->Module`)
6. paste above code into it
7. and... save file as *.xlsm file

To run code move cursor into the body of `GetDataByNearestDates` procedure and hit `F5`. The result set should looks like

```
2016-01-01 05:10    2016-01-01 05:07
2016-01-01 07:10    2016-01-01 07:10
2016-01-01 08:20    2016-01-01 08:19
2016-01-01 08:30    2016-01-01 08:27
2016-01-01 09:20    2016-01-01 09:18
2016-01-01 10:10    2016-01-01 10:13
2016-01-01 10:20    2016-01-01 10:23
2016-01-01 10:30    2016-01-01 10:30
2016-01-01 11:00    2016-01-01 10:57
2016-01-01 12:20    2016-01-01 12:20
2016-01-01 14:50    2016-01-01 14:50
2016-01-01 14:50    2016-01-01 14:54
2016-01-01 15:00    2016-01-01 15:00
2016-01-01 15:20    2016-01-01 15:20
2016-01-01 16:10    2016-01-01 16:12
2016-01-01 18:30    2016-01-01 18:26
2016-01-01 19:10    2016-01-01 19:08
2016-01-01 20:00    2016-01-01 20:00
2016-01-01 21:10    2016-01-01 21:15
2016-01-01 21:20    2016-01-01 21:15
2016-01-01 21:20    2016-01-01 21:20
2016-01-01 22:10    2016-01-01 22:10
2016-01-01 22:10    2016-01-01 22:13
2016-01-01 22:20    2016-01-01 22:18
```